# Google analytics Real time continously showing visitors from one location

Tags: google, google-analytics, real-time

I have two sites about tablet pc.
In "Real-Time" option in Google analytics, both sites at any movement of time shows active visitors from **Putney** which is located in UK. One the site is mytabletguru.com.

What I found odd is that both the sites is meant for the Indian audience as both have details about the tablet that are available in India.

Is this normal?

[image: Screenshots of Real Time]

Comment: Looks like the map is showing Putney in the United States, actually.

Comment: On my site appdunia.com, I also get continuous visitors from Putney. Main target for my website is majorly India. Why Putney people much interested in Indian sites :)

Comment: @DeependraSolanky Plz let me know if you got any related info. All of my sites are getting high traffic from Putney..

Answer (score 1):

Indian immigrants are all over the world, so I don't find it weird to have people visiting your website from random countries ;)

Besides that - it might be perfectly correct. Imagine a scenario where someone just has this website opened in a tab (along with few dozens of other sites) and simply forgot about it while working on some other stuff.

That's how I work quite often - right now my Firefox got ~30 tabs opened, I use roughly 10 of them, some of tabs I have got running weren't closed since 2 days or more, because I plan to get back to them, but don't have time for it now. So all of the owners for sites I got running see exactly what you do: That someone from one location visits a website constantly with almost no activity. Now, due to the setting on a browser it might be possible that each tab is tracked as separate visitor, but... all of them are from one location.

I know it's rather a cruel way of twisting the GA results ;) but that's just how some people work :)

Comment: Traffic from putney is coming form different browser and mostly from UCWEB and nokia phone browser.

Comment: In past week Putney ranked 10 for all the traffic source..

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, but I thought I should chip in for new visitors and people looking information on that specific "anomaly".

In my humble opinion answers the answer doesn't lie in immigrants in US or any other similar real life scenario.

In my experience, whenever I have a similar case of traffic coming from a specific town the reason is some kind of proxy or service.

e.g. Opera mini generates a lot of traffic appearing to come from one town. Since opera mini gets the page first, compresses it and then sends it to the mobile. So although the visitor is in India, the traffic you see seems to be coming from the datacenter town.

I have seen also traffic from Putney and the visitors patterns matches Indians living in India (not Indians in US). I know it sounds a bit as a wild guess but it isn't. I have noticed for example that visitors from Putney search for some words using the same misspellings that visitors from India use.

Generally in analytics, if there is smoke there is probably fire. If getting 1000 visitors from a specific city looks weird, it is probably because that's not what really happened.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking the bounce rate of the referral website. If it is above 90% then the traffic that you are receiving from this site is fake traffic. Many spam website sent auto generated traffic to the website to create attention. When I visited the website shown in the image, it seems the domain is expired.

If this is the case then try to filter this website by using Google analytic filter option.

Answer (score 0):

I see this for one of my popular websites which are targeted towards people from India too. I am still investigating why this is happening, but my guess is that this could be a service provider (e.g. Airtel) routing their traffic through a data center in Putney, USA.